# Need to call child_process.exec twice for it to work

Tags: node.js

In an node.js application I have the following code that is supposed to start a program called timestamp:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

child = exec('./timestamp 207.99.83.228 5000 -p 5500 &', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    } else {
        // Code to be executed after the timestamp program has started
        ...
    }
});
```

However, this will **not** start the timestamp program unless I **preceed** the call to exec by this:

```
exec('./timestamp 207.99.83.228 5000 -p 5500 &', null);
```

If I leave out this line, there is nothing, not even an error message.

So, in order to successfully start one instance of the program, I have to call exec **twice**. Is that some bug in node.js or the ChildProcess class or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do you include an & at the end? This should only be useful if your start your program from the console. Are there any errors in the callback. Does the callback get called?

Comment: @topek: Well, '&' makes the command run in the background. Is that  not necessary when the command is called by exec? And no, the callback is executed only after the second call when I call exec twice as stated in my question.

Comment: @topek: I just tried it without the '&', it didn't work. Strange as it is, I can only start the timestamp program when I add that nonsensical exec-call to the program and the '&' at the end of the command is needed as well.